# Create a two 2d array of pointers based on the same data

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I was trying create a 2d array of pointers based on other. Here is a base 2d array:

```
double **a = new double*[3];
a[0] = new double[3]{ 1, 2, 3 };
a[1] = new double[3]{ 4, 5, 6 };
a[2] = new double[3]{ 7, 8, 9 };
```

And I want create a 2x2 matrix which should look like this:

```
5,6
8,9
```

Finally, I was trying resolve the problem as follow:

```
double **b = &a[1];
b[0] = a[1];
b[1] = a[2];
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work as I expect. In addition, I would like to get access to data using negative indices eg. b[-1][-1] should return 1 value.

Comment: I suggest `double arr[][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };`, you probably don't need to allocate it on the heap. As for using negative indices, are you really sure that's what you want to do? It is definitely a nonstandard practice and unless you really know what you're doing, UB.

Comment: @szczurcio - I use this in image processing. To speed up calculations and don't check the boundaries of image every time, I want to create a matrix with border, where out of scope indices should return a default value.

Comment: Then how about rolling your own `Matrix2D` class where you overload `operator[]`? That would probably be best.

Comment: @szczurcio - I think when I overload an operator, I must use an IF statement which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Yup, you would have to do that. Well, if your negative indices will never be smaller than a certain value, you should refer to @Jarod42 's answer, otherwise I don't think you can do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With:

```
double a0[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
double a1[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
double a2[] = { 7, 8, 9 };

double* b0[3] = {&a0[1], &a1[1], &a2[1]};
double** b = &b0[1];
```

you can access with negative index and do:

```
for (int i = -1; i != 2; ++i) {
    for (int j = -1; j != 2; ++j) {
        std::cout << b[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, what happens if I do `b[-2][0]`?

Comment: @szczurcio: You will have out of bound access.

Comment: Indeed, so this doesn't solve OP's problem; the question says "I would like to get access to data using negative indices, *eg. b[-1][-1]*"; -1 is just an example, OP wants to be able to use negative indices in general.

Comment: @szczurcio: `b[42][42]` would also generate out of bound access, and it is with positive indexes. The offset for `-1` can be increase depending of needs, but the real array has still a limited size.

Answer (score 0):

This approach cannot work. One property of this kind of 2d array is that `&A[k+1] = &A[k]+1`, but that relationship does not hold between your desired `B[0]` and `B[1]`, because those are actually `&A[1][1]` and `&A[2][1]`, which could be miles apart.

What your code actually does is:

```
double **b = &a[1];  // all right, b points to part of a[]
b[0] = a[1];         // this assignment does nothing, they're already equal
b[1] = a[2];         // this assignment does nothing, they're already equal
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out some and get you on the right track.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Vec3 {
    union {
        double d3[3];
        struct {
            double x;
            double y;
            double z;
        };
    };

    double& operator[]( int idx );
};

double& Vec3::operator[]( int idx ) {
    return d3[idx];
}

typedef Vec3 Row;

struct Matrix {
    union {
        Row r[3];
        struct {
            Row row1;
            Row row2;
            Row row3;
        };
    };

    Row& operator[]( int idx );
};

Row& Matrix::operator[]( int idx ) {
    return r[idx];
}

int main() {

    Matrix m;
    m.row1.x = 1;
    m.row1.y = 2;
    m.row1.z = 3;

    m.row2.x = 4;
    m.row2.y = 5;
    m.row2.z = 6;

    m.row3.x = 7;
    m.row3.y = 8;
    m.row3.z = 9;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
            m[i][j] += 10;
            std::cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I did not add any error checking or bounds checking into the overloaded operator I just allowed the user to pass any value into it. This you would have to design to your specific needs. I'm just demonstrating an easy way to create a 2D Array or a Matrix like object using unions to have quick access to the subscript or bracket operator. I show a sample use of creating a 3x3 matrix with each value ranging from 1-9 then I use a double for loop to add 10 to each value then print out the new value within the array using the double brackets. This is all done on the stack which is better then using pointers and creating new memory for each place. If you need to use the heap then you could just assign this matrix class its own pointer and create it on the heap instead of every individual element. Another thing that can be done with this is if you need to use this for say int, float or some other data type you can easily template this class or structure.

As for indexing by a negative value; I have not heard of anyone doing so. This isn't to say that it can not be done, but from what I recall on how pointers & arrays behave with indexing according to their association with memory addressing they are 0 based index. This usually means that if we have a memory block a pointer to a double type variable, this usually means that each block of memory in most cases is 8 bytes wide. The very first element resides in the very first memory address location that is assigned to this variable for both the stack and the heap. If you try to use negative numbers which involve pointer arithmetic you begin to traverse memory that doesn't belong to this declared variable. To try and pull off what you are suggesting might require more than just basic C/C++ code can do, you might have to dive into asm to get something like this to work, especially if you want to avoid using if statements within the overloaded operators.